# How can I indicate a called function is checking that an object property is null so ts(18047) will not occur?

Tags: typescript, null-check

I have a helper function used in a few different places:

```
const eventCommonChecks(event: APIGatewayEvent): any {
  if(!event.body) {
    return {
      status: 400,
      body: 'Missing body'
    }
  }

  ... a few other checks
}
```

When that first function is called in a second function, the second function will return when `event.body` is null.  In the second function, we are guaranteed that `event.body` will not be null.  HOWEVER, if I don't use `event.body?.someFieldInBody`, the typescript compiler yells at me:  "event.body' is possibly 'null'.ts(18047)".

is there a way to decorate my common function to indicate that it's checking that `event.body` is not null?

```
const someLambda(event: APIGatewayEvent): any {
  const commonEventCheckResponse = eventCommonChecks(event);
  if (commonEventCheckResponse) {
    return commonEventCheckResponse;
  }


  //'event.body' is possibly 'null'.ts(18047)
  if (!event.body.someFieldInBody) {
    return {
      status: 400,
      body: 'Missing someFieldInBody'
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I know I can use use `!event.body?.someFieldInBody`, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: No since your `eventCommonChecks` already returns something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this:

1. Add a Non-null assertion operator ([ts docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator))

   `if (!event.body!.someFieldInBody) {`
2. Change the `event` type in `someLambda` function to a type where the `body` field is not null

**UPD: one more way to do it**

```
const someLambda(event: APIGatewayEvent): any {
    if (!event.body) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

so TS will see that now event.body cannot equal null (and other falsy values).

Comment: I ended up using the non-null assertion operator.  `event.body!`